# Edge case for accepts_nested_attributes and validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, associations

I have an `Account` model that accepts nested attributes for a user model. An Account `has_many users`. So a user cannot exist without an account. I wrote this validation:

```
# users.rb
validates :account_id, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

During sign up, a user fills the account form, and a nested user form. However, because the account does not yet exist, my tests are failing with this error:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors: ... @base=#<Account id: nil, title: "ACME Corp", subdomain: "acme1", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:"users.account_id"=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

I always want to ensure a valid account id exists for the user, unless the user is being created via a nested form in `Accounts#new`. In other words, when an `Account` is being created at the same time, in which case no account id exists yet to provide to the user.

Is there a way to do this?

It may be a moot point since all new users will be created via a current_account object, a la `current_account.users.build`. But I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In User model:

```
validates :account, :presence => true
```

In Account model:

```
has_many :users, :inverse_of => :account
```

This simply validates that the parent *object* is present - even if it hasn't been saved yet.

Comment: I tried this: `a = Account.new(subdomain: "test", title: "test", users_attributes: [{ name: "elmer", email: "fudd@example.com", password: "secret", password_confirmation: "secret"}])` Now, `a.valid?` returns this error: `@messages={:"users.account"=>["can't be blank"]`

Comment: ok, add this: ```has_many :users, :inverse_of => :account``` to your account model

Comment: That did it. I need to read on `ivnerse_of` and what it does, though. I'm new to this stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider:

```
validates_presence_of :account_id, only => :create
validates_numericality_of_account_id:, :null => true # or :only => :create
```

The seperation of the two cases and the use of the special helpers aids immediate readability.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't understand how that helps me though. Your example means that the validation does not get triggered when the user is being created... which is the opposite of what I want. I always want to make sure an account_id exists UNLESS an account is being created at the same time.

Comment: maybe you only want the second one with the `:null > true` ?

Comment: I still think it should be except > create but it's gonna be up to you to determine the final correct answer.  Hopefully these details give you enough to finalize it.

Comment: Michael, I think you misunderstood my question. When I say "account," I mean the object `Account` which `has_many :users`. So, I always want to validate for account_id when creating a user, except for when the user is being created through the Account object, via a nested form in `Accounts#create`.